# Can't install thrift gem on OS X El Capitan

Tags: ruby, rubygems, thrift

Trying to install thift gem after OSX El Capitan upgrade:

```
    $ gem install thrift
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing thrift:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/foo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160402-32256-7dzqel.rb extconf.rb
    checking for strlcpy() in string.h... yes
    creating Makefile

    make "DESTDIR=" clean

    make "DESTDIR="
    compiling binary_protocol_accelerated.c
    compiling bytes.c
    compiling compact_protocol.c
    compact_protocol.c:442:41: error: shifting a negative signed value is undefined [-Werror,-Wshift-negative-value]
        rb_exc_raise(get_protocol_exception(INT2FIX(-1), rb_str_new2(buf)));
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Compilation fails with
compact_protocol.c:442:41: error: shifting a negative signed value is undefined [-Werror,-Wshift-negative-value]

Comment: Did you accept the new Xcode EULA?

Comment: @CodeGnome yes I did

Comment: What is your gcc version?
Try using gcc 4.x. E.g. `brew install gcc49`, `ln -s /usr/local/bin/gcc-49 /usr/local/bin/gcc`. Make sure `gcc --version` returns the GNU compiler, not Apple LLVM and then install the gem: `gem install thrift`.

Comment: this is not a duplicate, I have the same error and I belive it relates to the description of the bug here: https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=202660. Basically an issue with ruby.h on ruby versions < 2.2 and the new gcc on elcapitan

Comment: @Anton: Now that I have reopened the question, please post your solution/ update as a fleshed out answer, rather than appending it to the question

Comment: @MichałKnapik thank you for the suggestion but that didn't work for me on El Capitan 10.11.4.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I have a solution for you! Hopefully.

Had this same problem the other day.

The problem is in the clang compiler that El Capitan comes bundled with. I'm sure it screws up other issues but this is one point that I had a lot of issues with.

Try running the following command and let me know how it goes!

```
gem install thrift -- --with-cppflags=\"-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Wno-shift-negative-value\"
```

Comment: This method didn't work for me. clang version: `Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)`, os x version: El Capitan 10.11.4

Comment: Might want to open up a separate question then with a full error output from that command so we can better help you!

Comment: This works with gem install, but bundle install is not working.
I tried `bundle config build.thrift "--with-cppflags=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0"` but that is not working, any idea on how to solve for -Wno-shift-negative-value option in bundle config?

Answer (score 20):

You need to escape double quotes.

> $ bundle config build.thrift "--with-cppflags=\"-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Wno-shift-negative-value\""
>
> ### $ cat ~/.bundle/config
>
> BUNDLE_BUILD__THRIFT: --with-cppflags="-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Wno-shift-negative-value"

Comment: That doesn't work for me: `BUNDLE_BUILD__THRIFT: "--with-cppflags=\"-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Wno-shift-negative-value\""`

Comment: For jenkins builds, I had to escape the space between the 2 variables: `bundle config build.thrift "--with-cppflags=\"-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0\ -Wno-shift-negative-value\""`

Answer (score 9):

There is help for **Big Sur** https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/issues/827#issuecomment-946388555

```
gem install thrift -v 0.15.0 -- --with-cppflags="-Wno-compound-token-split-by-macro"
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on mac bigsur

```
gem install thrift -v '0.10.0.0' -- --with-cppflags="-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-compound-token-split-by-macro"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
gem install thrift -v '0.9.0' -- --with-cppflags='-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0'
```

Comment: Release 0.9.0 is rather old an known to have severe issues. Not recommended.